# Best way of deploying a java app on Marathon

Tags: java, docker, marathon

As far as I understand how it works, I see two slightly different methods :

1. Method 1

- build a docker image containing all the stuff I need for my java app (the JAR
  for my app and the various JARs libraries).

  push the docker image on a repository (dockerhub)

  give the name of the image to marathon (using “docker” : {“image”: name_of_my_image}))

but the main drawback of is that I have to build/push a new image every time I make a modification to
my application code

2. Method 2

- build a docker image containing only the JARs that my application depends on (but without the JAR of
      my application)

  push this image on a repository

  put the JAR of my app on a web server

  give the name of the image to marathon and indicate the uris pointing to my web server to marathon

  ask marathon to use my image

every time I need to modify my image, I just have to push it on the web server.

Is the second method the correct way ? or does it exist other better approaches ?

Comment: I believe this is really opinion-based. Which is not really the place for it

Comment: May be there are some pros and cons for each method I am not aware of ...

Comment: If it helps you at all this isn't really specific to marathon and is a general docker image question. Typically you will see images closer to your first method though; a new version of your app = a new docker image.